# Through does not work with Subtract

Tags: functions, functional-style

```
Through[(Max - Min)[#]] & @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

gives

```
5 + (-Min)[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

Of course I can work around by

```
(Max[#] - Min[#]) & @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

to achieve the desired result

```
4
```

But I wonder why `Through` does not work with `Subtract` and if there is a direct way to use it.

---

Edit:

After reading the answers, I see the problem is actually from `Times` failing to play the role of an operator.

```
Subtract[Max, Min] // FullForm
```

gives

```
Plus[Max, Times[-1, Min]]
```

Here `Times` takes a number `-1` and a function `Min` as arguments and is expected to return a function just like what an operator should do, which unfortunately is not the case.

To solve by doing the operator's job manually:

```
Composition[Times[-1, #] &, Min]
```

and for the example:

```
Through[Plus[Max, Composition[Times[-1, #] &, Min]][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

Comment: Compare: `Max + Min // FullForm` and `Max - Min // FullForm`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Kuba pointed out, the issue here is that Mathematica doesn't do subtraction.  From the documentation on `Subtract`

> x-y is converted to x+(-1*y) on input.

And `Through` only applies the operators at the top level.  So

```
Through[(Max*Min)[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

and

```
Through[(Max + Min)[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

give 5 and 6, respectively, because their `FullForm` expressions are `Times[Max,Min]` and `Plus[Max,Min]`.

```
Through[(Max - Min)[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

tries to apply `Times[-1,Min]` to the arguement, but it is not a function.   So each element at the top level has to be a function.  Simple enough to solve:

```
Through[(Max + (-Min@# &))[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

gives the expected answer of 4.

Comment: Or for this specific case {i.e., use of `Min` and `Max`), `-Subtract @@ MinMax[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]` (note that `MinMax` is new in v10.1)

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility

```
Subtract @@ Through[{Max, Min}[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

4

Here `Through` returns {5, 1} and then `Subtract` finished the job

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem has its origins in how Mathematica performs subtractions, just don't use it till the very end:

```
Through[s[Max, Min][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]] /. s -> Subtract
(* 4 *)
```